# Using component level chunks in Nx and React

Tags: reactjs, nx.dev

In Nx is there a way to splits component level chunks in React application. If yes, then please share if someone had done this.

Currently, the only option that I see is commonChunk and namedChunks, but they does not serve the purpose.
Adding dynamic imports is not generating chunks. I tried using React.lazy and React Loadable but no success yet.
I am using nx web build executor.